# How one object of same class assign to the other object of the same class in c++?

Tags: c++, class, object, assignment-operator

I know that we can directly assign same class objects in C++,but what actually happen behind the scene?

Comment: The class' `operator=` is called? E.g for `a = b` (where `a` is an object) then `a.operator=(b)` will be called.

Answer (score 2):

There's something called "default [copy-constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)" and "default [assignment-operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment)". Unless you overload these methods in the class,  the default behavior is that all non-static members of the class are copied one-by-one from the source to the target class.

A little more: This includes pointers, btw. Which is why you generally should overload these operators and follow the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) if you have pointers as members.